# How do I merge tuples in a list based on the values?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list with tuples: (timestamp, someOtherValue). I would like to construct a new list with tuples like this: (timestamp, *sum of all someOtherValue for this timestamp*). I have tried to figure out some list comprehension, but I am stuck. Is there a clever way to do it, in Python?

Comment: Is the initial list sorted on the timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
l = [("timestamp1", 1),("timestamp1", 2),("timestamp1", 1),("timestamp2", 2)]
d = {}
for ts, val in l:
    d.setdefault(ts,0)
    d[ts] += val
print d.items()
[('timestamp2', 2), ('timestamp1', 4)]
```

Or use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict
l = [("timestamp1", 1),("timestamp1", 2),("timestamp1", 1),("timestamp2", 2)]
d = defaultdict(int)
for ts, val in l:
    d[ts] += val
print (d.items())
[('timestamp2', 2), ('timestamp1', 4)]
```

Comment: The first form should be `d[ts] = d.get(ts, 0) + val`, I would think.